# Custom Control vs Custom Behavior in WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

What is the difference between Custom Control and Custom Behavior?

Where Custom Control should be used and where Custom Behavior should be. in what ways they can be best used?

Answer (score 2):

**Behaviour** extends control functionalities

**Custom controls**  customize the visual of Control

Answer (score 2):

A behaviour can be used to extend the functionality of a control to do something that it cannot do on its own without having to modify or re-implement the entire control.

Consider for example the built-in TreeView control in WPF. It has a SelectedItem property that is read-only which means that you cannot two-way bind it to a property of your view model. If you don't want to implement your own custom TreeView control from scratch just because of this - which you probably don't :) - you could solve this by implementing a custom behaviour that sets the value of your source property whenever the value of the target property changes and vice versa. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this and an example: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/01/30/wpf-using-behaviours-to-bind-to-readonly-properties-in-mvvm/

The following article should also provide a good introduction to attached behvaiours: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF

So a behaviour is basically a piece of code that can be attached to some element in the XAML markup of a view through attached properties and add additional functionality to this element.

A control is a UI component that encapsulates some functionality and has a template such, as for example a Button or a ListBox.

Comment: You wouldn't have to reimplement TreeView in this case, just bind IsSelected on your list item viewmodel to IsSelected in the item container by overriding the style.  This way is friendly to virtualization (as soon as the item container is generated, it gets selected).  This is the intended usage in many item controls and is why SelectedItem is often readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviors **encapsulate** pieces of functionality into a reusable component.

**Custom controls** are **more work** than custom behaviors(White box vs black box)
Some things you have to do a custom control, eg Access Protected members.